# Building Android: Build error CtsAppBindingHostTestCases.LOCAL_TARGET_REQUIRED_MODULES : illegal value CtsAppBindingService1 : not a device module

Tags: android, android-source, lineageos, android-rom

I'm trying to build Android, specifically /e/OS/ (based on lineageOS), for my device (ZTE Blade V2020 / Codename P671F60) following [the official wiki](https://gitlab.e.foundation/e/documentation/a-generic-guide-on-porting-eos/-/wikis/07:-Building-an-e-ROM-the-Repo-Sync-way). I synced the sources, set up a minimal device tree (see below) and selected my device with lunch.

When I run `m`, the build runs some seconds, then I get an error.

Build output:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=10
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_P671F60
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=generic
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-6.5.7-artix1-1-x86_64-Artix-Linux
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=QQ3A.200805.001
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
[100% 1/1] initializing build system ...
build/make/core/board_config.mk:180: warning: Building a 32-bit-app-only product on a 64-bit device. If this is intentional, set TARGET_SUPPORTS_64_BIT_APPS := false
[ 37% 204/540] including frameworks/rs/Android.mk ...
build/make/core/module_arch_supported.mk: warning: RSUnbundledTests: Unknown installed file for module 'RSTestBackward' 
build/make/core/module_arch_supported.mk: warning: RSUnbundledTests: Unknown installed file for module 'RSTest_Compat' 
build/make/core/module_arch_supported.mk: warning: RSUnbundledTests19: Unknown installed file for module 'RSTestBackward19' 
build/make/core/module_arch_supported.mk: warning: RSUnbundledTests19: Unknown installed file for module 'RSTest_Compat19' 
[ 48% 263/540] including packages/apps/Backgrounds/Android.mk ...
/bin/bash: line 1: test: -gt: unary operator expected
[ 96% 523/540] including vendor/lineage/bootanimation/Android.mk ...
vendor/lineage/bootanimation/Android.mk:19: warning: TARGET_SCREEN_WIDTH is not set, using default value: 1080
vendor/lineage/bootanimation/Android.mk:23: warning: TARGET_SCREEN_HEIGHT is not set, using default value: 1920
[ 99% 539/540] finishing build rules ...
FAILED: 
build/make/core/main.mk:698: error: CtsAppBindingHostTestCases.LOCAL_TARGET_REQUIRED_MODULES : illegal value CtsAppBindingService1 : not a device module. If you want to specify host modules to be required to be installed along with your host module, add those module names to LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES instead.
13:40:00 ckati failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (13 seconds) ####
```

What causes this and how can I fix it?

---

My minimal device tree:

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

ifeq ($(TARGET_DEVICE),P671F60)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles,$(LOCAL_PATH))
endif
```

AndroidProducts.mk

```
PRODUCT_MAKEFILES := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/lineage_P671F60.mk

COMMON_LUNCH_CHOICES := \
    lineage_P671F60-user \
    lineage_P671F60-userdebug \
    lineage_P671F60-eng
```

lineage_P671F60.mk:

```
PRODUCT_DEVICE := P671F60
PRODUCT_NAME := lineage_P671F60
PRODUCT_BRAND := ZTE
PRODUCT_MODEL := ZTE Blade V2020
PRODUCT_MANUFACTURER := ZTE
```

BoardConfig.mk:

```
DEVICE_PATH := device/ZTE/P671F60

# Architecture
TARGET_ARCH := arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT := armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_ABI := arm64-v8a
TARGET_CPU_ABI2 := 
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT := generic

# Bootloader
TARGET_BOOTLOADER_BOARD_NAME := peach
TARGET_NO_BOOTLOADER := true

# Platform
TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM := mt6771
TARGET_BOARD_SUFFIX := _64
```